# How to not trigger on change event then change value via jQuery on ie11?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

On Chrome browser, I can use jQuery to set value for input like

```
$('#test').children('input[type=file]')[0].value = "";
```

and will not trigger any on change event,

However, on ie11, if you do same thing, the on change event will trigger automatically.

Any way to avoid that?

Comment: can you create a demo on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have IE11 then I just give you my solution, you can try it:

```
if (ie11) {
  unbind event onchange.
  change the value
  bind event onchange.
} else {
  change the value
}
```